# How do I get next fire date from a local notification..?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I am implementing a reminder application using `UILocalNotifications`, and want to allow user to set repeat mode. For repeating mode used `NSDayCalenderUnit`, `NSWeekCalendarUnit`, etc..

I didn't see any property in `LocalNotification` class to get the next fire date from a notification.

**Example**

> "{fire date = Friday,
>   September 6, 2013, 7:05:00 AM India Standard Time, time zone =
>   Asia/Kolkata (GMT+05:30) offset 19800, repeat interval =
>   NSWeekCalendarUnit, repeat count =
>   UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Friday,
>   September 6, 2013, 7:05:00 AM India Standard Time, user info = {\n
>   kRemindMeNotificationDataKey = \"Test Notification\";\n}}"

Any one please help me out to get the next fire date from a local notification.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have two properties from `UILocalNotification` which you can use:

1. fireDate
2. repeatInterval

Create a NSDate based on these two properties.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:self.localNotification.repeatInterval fromDate:self.localNotification.fireDate];

NSDate *nextFireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I am new to local notifications. I added a task with week repeat mode, get repeat interval as 256. So how do i create next fire date using that interval and fireDate.

Comment: fireDate: 2013-09-06 13:34:00 +0000
repeatInterval: 16 (NSDayCalendarUnit)

And I got 0001-01-05 18:06:32 +0000 instead of 2013-09-07 13:34:00 +0000

Comment: You dont need to create a next fire date. When in repeat mode it automatically created the next fire date using the NSCalendarUnit from repeatInterval. The answer I wrote is for you to know if you need it explicitly anyway. otherwise for firing LocalNotifications you dont need to give it another fireDate in case of repeat mode

Comment: Actually I wanted to show the next fireDate to user on my listings screen. So I need to calculate it.

Comment: By using the above mentioned.two properties you can calculate thr next ate and show it. I have shown you how to do it. Try it out. Tell me if it doesnot work.

Comment: What is the error? If there is none, please Edit the question and update it with the code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
NSCalendar *calendar = notification.repeatCalendar;
components.week = 1;
         if (!calendar) {
             calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
         }            
NSDate *nextFireDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:notification.fireDate options:0];
```